# Ejecuto función dentro de otra función en Javascript con consultas a BD Firestore y no me devuelve el valor correctamente

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

Tengo una función sencilla que me debe agregar un nuevo registro a mi colección Firestore, simplemente verificando mediante otra función que me devuelve la cantidad de día entre dos fechas para cumplir cierta condición. Adjunto el código.

```
function VentaAnterior(CodCon){ 
    var dias=10; //ASumiendo que nunca ha comprado, asigno el valor 10 por defecto
    db.collection("Ventas").where("CodCon","==",String(CodCon)).orderBy("FecVen", "desc").limit(1)  
        .get().then(function(querySnapshot){
        //Trae de la colección ventas la ultima venta del Consumidor recibido
        querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
            //SI existe venta me calcula la diferencia entre la fecha actual y la anterior
            var FecAnt=new Date(doc.data().FecVen.seconds*1000);            
            var FecAct=new Date();      
            dias=FecAct-FecAnt;                     
            dias=Math.trunc(dias/(1000*60*60*24));          
        });     
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    }); 
    return dias; //devuelve la cantidad de días
}
function AgregarVenta(CodCon){  
    dias=VentaAnterior(CodCon);//LLama a mi función donde obtengo la ultima fecha
    if(Number(dias)>=7){//Si es mayor a una semana registra una nueva venta     
        var pFecVen=document.getElementById('eFecVen').value;
        var pCanGLP=document.getElementById('eCanGLP').value;
        var dd=pFecVen.substring(0,2);
        var mm=pFecVen.substring(3,5);
        var aaaa=pFecVen.substring(6);
        var CodVen=dd+mm+aaaa+CodCon;
        var eFecVen=new Date(aaaa+'/'+mm+'/'+dd);
        var docVentaHoy = db.collection('Ventas').doc(CodVen);
        docVentaHoy.set({
            FecVen: new firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date(eFecVen)),           
            CodCon: CodCon,
            CanGLP: pCanGLP,
            LogUsr: Usuario.email           
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
        });             
    }
    else{//SI es menor da una alerta y limpia la pantalla
        alert("El Consumidor "+CodCon+" ya realizó una compra hace "+dias+" días.");
    }
    LimpiarVenta();
}
```

El problema es que al correr la función, SIEMPRE me agrega un nuevo registro y después ejecuta la función VENTAANTERIOR y obviamente me retorna el valor de 0 porque ya agregó una VENTA en ese día, por tanto no me valida el tiempo de 7 días transcurridos entre venta y venta.
La verdad que algo tan sencillo no se en que falla. Agradecería cualquier ayuda.

Comment: Hola. ¿Porque haces un foreach para calcular días?... Piensa que devolverás solo el cálculo de días del último registro del bucle... (Es cierto que ordenas la consulta por FecVen)... ¿Has realizado un debug de la función calcula los dias?  (Añade un console.log con ese dato en el bucle para ver si hace lo que deseas según tu BD)

Comment: el problema es que antes de hacer el foreach, hace el registro y no se por qué? soy novato en java, pero la lógica supongo que es la misma; entonces al hacer el alta, siempre el foreach me devuelve 0 porque ya adicionó un registro en ese día, así que no me está controlando nada

Comment: Hola, tu problema es que no estas manejando correctamente los métodos aíncronos de firestore

Answer (score 0):

> El problema es que al correr la función, SIEMPRE me agrega un nuevo registro y después ejecuta la función VENTAANTERIOR y obviamente me retorna el valor de 0 porque ya agregó una VENTA en ese día, por tanto no me valida el tiempo de 7 días transcurridos entre venta y venta.

Bien, vamos por partes. Primero que nada te recomiendo que leas sobre [promesas](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise)

PRIMERO:

En tu función `VentaAnterior` no estás manejando correctamente la [promesa](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise) que devuelve el método `.get()` de la collection

```javascript
function VentaAnterior(CodCon){ 
    var dias=10;
    db.collection("Ventas").where("CodCon","==",String(CodCon)).orderBy("FecVen", "desc").limit(1)  
        .get() // El .get() devuelve una promesa
        .then(function(querySnapshot){
        //Trae de la colección ventas la ultima venta del Consumidor recibido
        querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
            //SI existe venta me calcula la diferencia entre la fecha actual y la anterior
            var FecAnt=new Date(doc.data().FecVen.seconds*1000);            
            var FecAct=new Date();      
            dias=FecAct-FecAnt;                     
            dias=Math.trunc(dias/(1000*60*60*24));          
        });     
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    }); 
    return dias; //devuelve la cantidad de días
}
```

Ahora bien, para explicar mejor lo de "no estas manejando bien la promesa". Voy a simplificar tú función para que sea evidente el problema:

```javascript
1 function VentaAnterior(CodCon){ 
2    var dias=10;
3    db.collection("Ventas").where("CodCon","==",String(CodCon)).limit(1)  
4        .get() // El .get() devuelve una promesa
5        .then(function(querySnapshot){ ... }); // <- El then es una funcion que se ejecuta una vez que se resuelve la promesa (en el futuro, no ahora)   
6    return dias; //devuelve la cantidad de días
}
```

- En la línea `2` la variable dias se inicializa en `10`.
- Luego en la línea `3` se llama a la función `.get()` de una collection de firestore.
- Por último en la línea `6` tu función (inmediatamente después de ejecutar la línea `3`) devuelve el valor de la variable `dias` que es igual a `10`.
  Ya que la promesa no se ha resuelto todavía y por ende no ha modificado el valor de tu variable días como tu esperabas.

Esto contesta a:

> SIEMPRE me agrega un nuevo registro

Porque en tu función `AgregarVenta`, si `dias >= 7` (Siempre lo es), creas un nuevo documento:

```javascript
function AgregarVenta(CodCon){  
    dias=VentaAnterior(CodCon);//Siemrpe obtendras el valor '10'
    if(Number(dias)>=7){//Si es mayor a una semana registra una nueva venta     
        //...
        docVentaHoy.set({ // <- Creas el nuevo documento
            //...         
        })             
    }
}
```

Con respecto a:

> y después ejecuta la función VENTAANTERIOR

Creo que hay una equivocación ahí. Ya que según tu código, primero ejecutas la función `VentaAnterior` y luego creas el documento.

En tanto a:

> y obviamente me retorna el valor de 0 porque ya agregó una VENTA en ese día

No estoy seguro que eso sea correcto, no veo en ningún lado que devuelvas el valor 0.

En fin. Para solucionar tu problema debes hacer lo siguiente:

```javascript
function VentaAnterior(CodCon){ 
    let dias=10;
    return db.collection("Ventas").where("CodCon","==",String(CodCon)).orderBy("FecVen", "desc").limit(1)  
        .get()
        .then((querySnapshot) => {
            if(querySnapshot.empty){ // Chequeo si hay documentos encontrados
              return dias;
            } else {
               const doc = querySnapshot.docs[0]; // No hace falta usar forEach ya que el limit es 1.
               let FecAnt=new Date(doc.data().FecVen.seconds*1000);            
               let FecAct=new Date();      
               dias=FecAct-FecAnt;                     
               dias=Math.trunc(dias/(1000*60*60*24));
               return dias; //Acá devuevlo dias.
            }     
         }).catch((error) => {
            console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
         });
}
function AgregarVenta(CodCon){  
    VentaAnterior(CodCon)
      .then(dias => { // VentaAnterior devuelve una promesa ahora.
         if(dias >= 7){ // Dias ahora está bien calculado.
           let pFecVen=document.getElementById('eFecVen').value;
           let pCanGLP=document.getElementById('eCanGLP').value;
           let dd=pFecVen.substring(0,2);
           let mm=pFecVen.substring(3,5);
           let aaaa=pFecVen.substring(6);
           let CodVen=dd+mm+aaaa+CodCon;
           let eFecVen=new Date(aaaa+'/'+mm+'/'+dd);
           let docVentaHoy = db.collection('Ventas').doc(CodVen);
           docVentaHoy.set({
             FecVen: new firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date(eFecVen)),           
             CodCon: CodCon,
             CanGLP: pCanGLP,
             LogUsr: Usuario.email           
           })
            .catch(function(error) {
               console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
            });             
         } else{
            alert("El Consumidor "+CodCon+" ya realizó una compra hace "+dias+" días.");
         }
         LimpiarVenta();
      });
}
```

Espero que te sirva. Si hay algun error de sintaxis u otra cosa me avisas para corregirlo (No usé ningun IDE)